# Magento SQLSTATE[42000] on Product View

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, magento, e-commerce

i am currently working on a online shop with magento. Everything worked fine and went the way i wanted it to. But suddenly i got this error message when i try to get an product view.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

The strange thing is that i only changed some layout and template files, but they had nothing to do with my single-product-view pages. I didnt change any core-related files or anything with an SQL-Query in it..
I've looked through the pages i edited but there seems nothing wrong.

Maybe this is some known error. On another thread i read that i had to clear my errorlog / error-table, but that did nothing.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

- Philipp

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean cache
2. Check every statement where you do something like:

```
    addAttributeToFilter...
    $collection->getSelect...
```

Or something like this. Because it might be that you changed some filter or remover some block or made some typo.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is exceptionally vague. Given the lack of information I can only suggest a standard debug method.

1. Revert the theme to `base/default` and see if the error persists
2. Rename the `app/code/local` directory to `app/code/local.bak` and see if the error persists
3. Rename the `app/code/community` directory to `app/code/community.bak` and see if the error persists
4. Restore a clean version of the `app/code/core` directory (just in case a rogue developer modified it)
5. Restore a clean version of the `lib` directory (again, just in case a rogue developer modified it)
6. Give up hope

Answer (score 0):

There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Trace:

```
#0 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
#3 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
#4 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(725): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#5 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(844): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#6 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Abstract.php(630): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
#7 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
#8 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category))
#9 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(133): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_getProductCollection()
#10 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(752): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
#11 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#12 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(753): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#13 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(520): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(471): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('featuredproduct...', true)
#15 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/thungracnhua/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(66): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('featuredproduct...')
#16 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(212): include('/home/admin/dom...')
#17 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(239): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#18 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(253): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#19 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(753): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(389): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#22 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(153): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#23 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#24 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#25 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(177): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#26 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#27 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#28 /home/admin/domains/vinatoppro.com/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#29 {main}
```

website : http://vinatoppro.com